# Notification sound in android

Tags: android

In my android application, I want to notify the user with a sound without showing the notification. Is that possible ?

```
Notification n = new Notification();
                n.icon = com.android.mms.R.drawable.wap_message;
                n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

This is the code I am using to show the notification, So I commented icon and flags of the notification as follows

```
Notification n = new Notification();
                //n.icon = com.android.mms.R.drawable.wap_message;
                n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                //n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `MediaPlayer` instead of `Notification` to play the notification sound. If you use the Notication then it shows the icon. In your case using the `MediaPlayer` is better option.